# PlusClient onConnected is not triggred

Tags: android, google-plus

im trying to use google pluse auto log in.

I use the SignInButton button widget.

When i click on log in i see the progress dialog but onConnected  is not getting triggred

This my buttom press code:

```
case R.id.sign_in_button:
        {
            if(!mPlusClient.isConnected())
            {
                if (mConnectionResult == null) {
                    {
                        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterPage.this);
                        pDialog.setMessage("logging in...");
                        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                        pDialog.show();
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                        // Try connecting again.
                        mConnectionResult = null;
                        mPlusClient.connect();
                    }
                }

            break;
        }
```

My onConnected code:

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Log.i("ok", "ok");

        if (mPlusClient.getCurrentPerson() != null && isNetworkAvailable())
            new GooglePlusRegister().execute();
        else
        {
            if(pDialog != null)
                pDialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

The progress dialog is not dissmisng and i dont see my Log call.

in my onCreate:

```
mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this , this).setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN).setVisibleActivities("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity").build();
```

Imports:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look again at your code: `mPlusClient.connect()` is never being executed.

The conditional statement `if (mConnectionResult == null)` is only showing the ProgressDialog without actually connecting to Google Plus.

I'd have to review the correct way of handling error conditions, but off the top of my head, simply removing the line for the `else` statement may resolve your issue.